# What is this line of code doing?

Tags: ios, swift

This is from public Eureka project on Github. I'm trying to understand the source code (and Swift generics). I'm stuck on the very last line here on this snippet. What is the last line doing?

```
open class Row<Cell: CellType>: RowOf<Cell.Value>, TypedRowType where Cell: BaseCell {

    /// Responsible for creating the cell for this row.
    public var cellProvider = CellProvider<Cell>()

    /// The type of the cell associated to this row.
    public let cellType: Cell.Type! = Cell.self //what is this line doing?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's assigning the property `cellType` to the type of `Cell` that this generic was specialized over. So if this is a `Row<PersonCell>`, `cellType` is `PersonCell`.

The `!` here is almost certainly unnecessary, and can create some headaches using this in Swift 3.

Comment: thanks, I was mainly confused about the ! but good explanation clearing up the whole line for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.self` as a static attribute of a class retrieves the type of that class.

So if `Row<CustomCell>` the `cellType` will have `CustomCell.Type` assigned.

Comment: What is the difference between Cell.self and Cell.Type?

Comment: `Cell.self` is just an explicit way of writing `Cell` (as a type). Swift requires the `.self` to avoid mistakes. `Cell.Type` is the type of the type `Cell`. The "type of a type" is called a meta-type. So if you think about `myView`, it an instance of the type `UIView`, but what is `UIView` and instance of? It's an instance of the type `UIView.Type`. (And of course you might ask, what is `UIView.Type` an instance of? Well, in Swift, nothing. Because meta-types are not themselves first-class types; if they were we could create several interesting types that are impossible in Swift like Functor.)